# React native add active class when push the button

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have a 3 buttons on react native project iOS app.  How can I set class active to clicked button and delete this class from others? Like addClass/removeClass that I had used on jquery?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First have your define your style "class".

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  btnSelected: {
     ...
  },
  notSelected : {
  }
});
```

Then you can use a state property in your react component.

example :

```
state = {
  btnSelected: 1
}

<Button 
    style={(this.state.btnSelected== 1)?styles.btnSelected:styles.notSelected}
    onPress={() => this.setState({ btnSelected: 1 })} ... />
<Button 
    style={(this.state.btnSelected== 2)?styles.btnSelected:styles.notSelected} ... 
    onPress={() => this.setState({ btnSelected: 2 })} .../>
<Button 
    style={(this.state.btnSelected== 3)?styles.btnSelected:styles.notSelected} 
    onPress={() => this.setState({ btnSelected: 3 })} ... />
```

Answer (score 2):

The key concept in React and React Native is, that you don't imperatively set the state of your UI. Instead, you change some state, and then declaratively render the UI based on that.

You could, for example use the local component state (`this.state`):

```
  class Buttons extends React.Component {
    state = {
      activeButton: 'first'
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <View>
          <Button
            onPress={() => this.setState({ activeButton: 'first' })}
            isActive={this.state.activeButton === 'first'}
          />
          <Button
            onPress={() => this.setState({ activeButton: 'second' })}
            isActive={this.state.activeButton === 'second'}
          />
          <Button
            onPress={() => this.setState({ activeButton: 'third' })}
            isActive={this.state.activeButton === 'third'}
          />
        </View>
      )
    }
  }
```

The `onPress` event handler sets local component state with `setState`, which causes the component to immediately re-render. The `isActive` property is then set on all the buttons based on the expression that compares `this.state.activeButton` with some value.